# About the behaviour of id on an instance method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following script:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass

a = A()
b = A()
print map(id, [A.f, a.f, b.f])
print map(id, [a.f, b.f])
```

Out:

```
[4299312976, 4298026672, 4299370816]
[4299312976, 4298026672]
```

- why does the `id` of `A.f` become the `id` of `a.f`?
- why does the `id` of `a.f` become the `id` of `b.f`?

Now I do this:

```
print "{0} {1} {2}".format(id(A.f), id(a.f), id(b.f))
```

Out:

```
4299312976 4299312976 4299312976
```

Why do they have the same `id` now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access `A.f` an object is created, of type `<unbound method>`. You can see this is the case with:

```
print map(id, [A.f, A.f, A.f])
```

where the `id` value won't be the same. The same happens for `a.f` and `b.f` but in this case the type is `<bound method>` because the object remembers which instance the code needs to act on.

These objects are garbage collected once you don't reference them any more. So:

```
map(id, [A.f, a.f, b.f])
```

creates 3 objects (4 including the list containing them) and passes them to the function `id`. Once the `map` call is terminated list and the objects are collected and memory is freed.

In the second call new objects are created and the memory for the object created for `A.f` has been reused (thus you get he same `id`).

In the last example you're calling `id` each time explicitly on an object that is immediately discarded, and the memory happens to be reused immediately.

This apparently "magical" object creation when accessing a method happens because of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).