# Applying `id` to a method is always different in IPython. Can someone explain this odd behavior?

Tags: python, ipython

I ran across a Python behavior that seems very strange to me, and I would like to understand it.

Normally I expect the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function to always return the same value when I pass the same object to it. In CPython it corresponds to the location of the object in memory.

When I create an object and apply `id` the result is always the same, but when I use `id` on a bound method of the object the result changes. Why is this? Is a new method being created each time I get the method attribute?

I first noticed this in IPython, but it was more difficult to make a script that shows the same behavior. Maybe this is partially an IPython thing?

I did manage to write a small block that partially recreates the behavior.

```
# Create an object

class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        pass

obj = Foo()

for _ in range(10):
    print(id(obj))
# ... prints the same number

for _ in range(10):
    print(id(obj.bar))
# ... in this case the first number is different and the rest are the same
```

This is slightly different than just pasting the line `print(id(obj.bar))` into IPython a bunch of times because the returned ids are *mostly* consistent. However, when I just run the above code as a python script, all the numbers are the same, so it seems that this is an IPython quirk. I guess the question now is: why?

Comment: Can't reproduce i my ipython (5.1.0) and version of python (2.7.6).  What Python version are you running and what version of IPython?

Comment: @JayAtkinson interesting. I *am* able to reproduce with ipython 5.1.0 with Python 2.7.12

Comment: Not marking as duplicate yet because I am not 100% sure they are the same, but certainly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26201305/3642398

Comment: @JayAtkinson I ran this on IPython 5.1.0, Python 2.7.12  and Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound method is not the same as unbound class function:

```
In [539]: Foo.bar
Out[539]: <function __main__.Foo.bar>
In [540]: id(Foo.bar)
Out[540]: 2951600788
In [541]: obj=Foo()
In [542]: obj.bar
Out[542]: <bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0xaf63c0cc>>
In [543]: id(obj.bar)
Out[543]: 2942557836
In [544]: obj1=Foo()
In [545]: id(obj1.bar)   # different obj, different bound method
Out[545]: 2996305612
In [546]: id(obj.bar)    # different from the previous time
Out[546]: 2942663116
```

So it is creating a new bound method each time you reference it.

All the bound methods link to the same unbound method, `Foo.bar`:

```
In [549]: obj.bar.__func__
Out[549]: <function __main__.Foo.bar>
In [550]: id(obj.bar.__func__)
Out[550]: 2951600788
In [551]: id(obj1.bar.__func__)
Out[551]: 2951600788
```

Answer (score 4):

Every time you retrieve a method from a class instance, you get a *bound method* which will fill in the instance as the first parameter (`self`) when called.  A new bound method is created every time.  However, in your test, only one bound method exists at a time; the previous becomes eligible for garbage collection before you create the next one.  It is therefore likely (but by no means guaranteed) that the new bound method will be allocated at the same address as the one just freed, and therefore will have the same id.  If you collected them all in a list, so that they all existed at the same time, they would definitely have distinct ids.

Answer (score 0):

It is because python creates objects in the run time. When you start your script, object is created once and you can see the same number in each loop iterations. When you use this print in separate entries in IPython new objects are created.